# Generics and Constrained Polymorphism versus Subtyping

Tags: oop, programming-languages, scala, haskell, functional-programming

In this [PDF presentation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/haskell-retrospective/ECOOP-July09.pdf) on Haskell Type Classes,  slide #54 has this question:

> **Open Question**:
>
> In a language with generics and
>   constrained polymorphism, do you need
>   subtyping too?

My questions are:

1. How do generics and constrained polymorphism make subtyping unnecessary?
2. If generics and constrained polymorphism make subtyping unnecessary, why does Scala have subtyping?

Comment: You might be interested in Scalaz, which used constrained (aka ad-hoc) polymorphism extensively. Type inference in Scala does not work in many places as Haskell, which can make it laborious to encode type classes. But we try anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oleg Kiselyov and Ralf Lämmel's ["Haskell's overlooked object system"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0509027v1.pdf) proposes a library for Haskell that implements an object system using Haskell's existing features, including type classes.

An excerpt from the "introduction" section of the paper (emphasis mine):

> The interest in this topic is not at all restricted to Haskell researchers and practitioners since there is a fundamental and unsettled question — a question that is addressed in the present paper:
>
> **What is the relation between type-class-bounded and subtype polymorphism?**
>
> In this research context, we speciﬁcally (and emphatically) restrict ourselves to the
>   existing Haskell language (Haskell 98 and common extensions where necessary),
>   i.e., no new Haskell extensions are to be proposed. **As we will substantiate, this
>   restriction is adequate, as it allows us to deliver a meaningful and momentous answer to the aforementioned question.**

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for >2 years ago. :-)

Comment: Seems like development on OOHaskell is still somewhat active: https://github.com/nkaretnikov/OOHaskell

Answer (score 29):

> How do generics and constrained polymorphism make subtyping unnecessary?

**It is not known that they do.**  If you put the slide in context, I think that the argument the speaker was trying to make goes something like this:

- In the old days, subtyping provided an important kind of polymorphism.
- Also in the old days, in another country, type abstraction and type parameters provided an important kind of polymorphism.  This kind is known in its native land as *parametric polymorphism*, but in foreign lands it is called *generics*.
- Modern generics admit of constraints, sometimes called "bounded polymorphism", which can achieve many of the same things as subtype polymorphism.
- Subtyping carries with it substantial baggage—in particular, you have to worry about covariance and contravariance.  Languages wind up with uncomfortable restrictions, heavyweight notations, and sometimes outright safety violations (e.g., Eiffel).

The open question: perhaps constrained *parametric* polymorphic solves enough of the same problems that in the happy future, we can get rid of subtype polymorphism entirely, and with it the nasty question of when subtyping is covariant, contravariant, and invariant.

Answer (score 14):

Well if that is indeed an open question, then by definition we don't know the answer to #1.  The design spaces are pretty different, and it isn't obvious to me how you might directly encode subtyping into constrained polymorphism.  The encoding is direct when the *arguments* are polymorphic.  For example, a Haskell function with type

```
foo :: (Num a) => a -> Bool
```

is equivalent to, say:

```
Bool foo(Num x)
```

in an OO language.  However it is not clear how to encode:

```
// I will return some Num, but I'm not going to tell you what kind exactly
Num bar(Bool x)
```

into constrained polymorphism, nor is it clear how to encode:

```
-- I can return any kind of Num, *you* tell *me* what kind
bar :: (Num a) => Bool -> a
```

into subtyping.

My best guess for #2 is that Scala has to talk to Java, and Java talks about subtyping.  And because Scala has every type system feature known to man because it thinks it has to in order to be cool.  :-P

Comment: In Haskell you always can get OO behaviour (returning pointer to abstract object) by adding `data ANum = forall a . (Num a, NumCoerce a) => ANum a`

Comment: For "I can return any kind of Num, *you* tell *me* what kind" how about variant `Num bar(Bool x, NumFactory f)` (of course that sometimes will lead to casting from `Num` to actual type produced by `f`)

Comment: If rank-2 polymorphism is allowed, you can express "Num bar(Bool x)" as "Bool -> (forall n. Num n => n -> a) -> a"

Comment: @ony in Java you can avoid the cast by doing something like `<N extends Num> N bar(Bool x, Factory<N> f)`.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves, yep you can use generics/templates to avoid upcasting. But you should remember that Java and C# both tries to achieve high compatibility in run-time. And I believe that constraints on generics are not part of the method. Thus there should be non-specialized version that works with template parameters as with `Object` or interfaces (you may want to look [one of my posts about this](http://virkony.blogspot.com/2010/12/genericsspecialization-vs-plain.html)).

Answer (score 5):

2 is easy: because Java (and JVM bytecode) has it. If we want to usefully call Scala from Java, we pretty much have to allow extending Java interfaces and classes; and if Scala classes get translated to JVM classes (and traits to interfaces), then we can extend them as well.

The same reason why Scala has `null` :)

As to 1, you also need to have existential types for encoding the

```
Num bar(Bool x)
```

case:

```
bar :: Bool -> exists a. Num a
```