# What are types with type constraints called?

Tags: haskell, ghc

For example, `Num a => a`.

I assumed they're just called "constrained types", but Googling didn't turn up many uses of that term so I'm curious to know if they go by some other name.

Comment: I'm not into haskell, but are you talking about enumerable types?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg No, he's not. What makes you think of enums here? He's talking about type constraints like `<T extends Foobar>` in Java.

Comment: @sepp2k I interpreted "types with type constraints" as "types which are allowed only to have one of specific values". Thanks for the Java example, that's my kind of language ;)

Comment: Ok then, another attempt (my second and last attempt): Are you talking about "generics"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg He's specifically talking about polymorphic types ("generics" in Java terminology) that have type constraints (like "<T extends Foobar>" as opposed to just "<T>" in Java).

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg The most similar would be a generic constrained by an interface (`<T extends IFoo>`.

Comment: I thought the "haskell" tag would be enough to indicate that I'm talking about something in Haskell, not Java. :-)

Comment: Yes, the closest thing Java has are probably bounded wildcards, though they aren't exactly equivalent. In Java if you say `x`'s type is `T extends Number` then `x` is *some* kind of `Number`, you just don't know/care which. (And indeed, this is only subtly different from saying `x`'s type is `Number`.) My understanding is that in Haskell, saying `x`'s type is `Num a => a` is more like saying `x` is *every* kind of `Num` simultaneously. You can then pass x to something that only takes `Double` or to something else that only takes `Integer`.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves That isn't accurate. Generics in Java *do* behave like polymorphism in Haskell. If you have a generic Java method with <T extends Number> and its return type is T, then that method can return every kind of Number, not just some kind of Number (you can specifically ask for a certain kind of Number by calling `myMethod<Integer>` or `myMethod<Float>`). Of course it's impossible to define any useful method (meaning a method that doesn't just return null for example) with that return type unless it also takes at least one parameter of type T.

Comment: @sepp2k You're right! I was thinking that it isn't possible (in Java) to have a method that returns such a type without it appearing in the types of the method parameters, but I was wrong. Like you mention, it's less powerful than in Haskell, though it isn't *entirely* useless. For example, in `Collections.emptySet` (and friends) `E` is only in the return type (not as the type itself, but as a type parameter) and the result is an empty set of any kind of object. The difference in Haskell is that you can do this with "non-empty" stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Qualified types". See Mark P. Jones. *Qualified Types: Theory and Practice*. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1994.

Plenty of relevant [matches on Google](http://www.google.nl/search?q=qualified%20types).

Answer (score 8):

Types with this particular kind of constraints are called *"qualified types"*, and the feature itself sometimes "qualified polymorphism". I believe the terminology was originally introduced by [Mark Jones' ESOP '92 paper](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/esop92.html).

Qualified types should not be confused with the more mainstream notion of "bounded polymorphism", on which generics in languages like Java are based. Bounded polymorphism essentially is the (rather complicated) combination of parametric polymorphism with subtyping, whereas qualified types get along without subtyping.

Answer (score 6):

I'm no type theory expert, but with a little research, this is what I've found (which may or may not be helpful, but I can't fit this in a comment).

[A Gentle Introduction to Haskell: Classes](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) calls the `Num a` portion the type's context:

> The constraint that a type a must be an instance of the class Eq is
>   written Eq a. Thus Eq a is not a type expression, but rather it
>   expresses a constraint on a type, and is called a *context*.

So I suppose you could say "a type with a context", or as you mentioned "constrained type".

Another place to look is where type-classes are first described (I believe) for Haskell: [How to make ad-hoc polymorphism less ad-hoc](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/class/class.ps.gz) [postscript].

> Type classes appear to be closely related to issues that arise in
>   object-oriented programming, bounded quantification of types, and
>   abstract data types[CW85, MP85, Rey85]. Some of the connections are
>   outlined below, but more work is required to under-stand these
>   relations fully.

This paper was written in 1988, so I'm not sure if these relations are now fully understood, but the wikipedia page for [Bounded quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification) doesn't mention Haskell, so I'm not sure it's exactly the same thing. (once again, not a type theorist -- just a guy who likes Haskell)

Also, about the type `square :: Num a => a -> a` it says:

> This is read, "`square` has type `a -> a`, for every `a` such that `a` belongs
>   to class `Num` (i.e., such that `(+)`,`(*)`, and negate are defined on `a`)."

You could say the type "belongs to a class".

That's about all I've got.  Personally, I think "constrained types" or "types constrained to a class" work fine.

Comment: Regarding the relationship between OOP and bounded quantification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707171/generics-and-constrained-polymorphism-versus-subtyping

Answer (score 6):

The `Num a =>` part is indeed called a constraint; you can read it as "if `Num a` is true, then ..."

Normally, constraints and quantifiers are discussed together.  Any constrained type can be converted to an equivalent type where constraints only appear just inside `forall` or `exists` quantifiers.  So, you won't hear of "constrained types" as often as you will hear of "constrained parametric polymorphism" (`forall a. C => T`), "constrained existential types" (`exists a. C => T`), or "constrained polymorphism" (both kinds of quantifiers).

A related term is "bounded polymorphism."  Bounded polymorphism usually means constrained polymorphism where the constraint is a subtype or supertype constraint.  However, this distinction isn't strictly followed.  In languages with subtyping like Java or Scala, you will often hear any kind of constraint called a "bound."

Comment: When I ask ghci for the type of `5` it says `5 :: (Num t) => t`. Are you saying that that's actually a `forall` or `exists`? If so, which one?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves That type is `forall t. (Num t) => t`.  Free variables in types are implicitly quantified with `forall`.  There is no `exists` keyword; existential types only occur in combination with data constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You could call it a *bounded polymorphic type* (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification)).

Comment: The phrase "universal or existential quantifiers which are restricted ("bounded") to range only over the subtypes of a particular type" on that page leaves me skeptical.  Even though Haskell typeclasses seem pretty similar to interfaces in Java, I don't think what they provide really constitutes "subtyping". If they were subtypes, then that would mean the type system violates LSP. For example, the `>>=` method of `Monad` and the `==` method of `Eq` both have methods that take parameters that are "more specific" in their instances.

Comment: I agree, Haskell certainly doesn't have subtyping (for which this term is actually used.) Still, it looks similar to me if you actually think of it as literal "bounded quantification": `forall a. a<:T => ...` is just a kind of a predicate in the quantifier, similar to `forall a. N(a) => ...` (thinking in predicate logic here). Maybe a better expression would be "class-bounded polymorphic type". But here, I'd find the simple "constrained type" much simple.